# Was IonPaginationModule discontinued?

Tags: ionic-framework

Can't find any docs on this module. Cant import it using Ionic 6.2. Tried to implement pagination on my Ionic project with IonPaginationModule, but cant import it.

Comment: I find no mention of IonPaginationModule. Please post code or what gave you the idea you should use this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no mention of IonPaginationModule anywhere.

Maybe you are looking for `NgxPaginationModule` from https://github.com/michaelbromley/ngx-pagination ?